# WPA2-Enterprise - unable to find a way around Lanner Electronics

Tags: wifi, nmap, wpa2, spoofing

I have currently been working in an environment where I am connected to a WPA2-Enterprise network requiring me to enter my username and password for the network whenever I connect. I have been asked to do some security analysis and have come across a couple of issues.

1. When I connect to the network and execute a quick ifconfig there seems to be far more than one value for 0.x.0.0 the x value. (it changes everytime I connect)
2. This then lead me to wonder what an nmap scan would look like. Just a normal -sP scan to list alive hosts. When I ran this scan it presented me with 254 hosts all alive and all under the name of Lanner Electronics all with the same MAC address.

I know the network has 802.1x running on it and has many more users than me, however I cannot seem to figure out how to get around whatever it is that is preventing me from discovering ACTUAL devices and their open ports. I have tried spoofing my MAC address, however nothing changed. I have tried different credentials, nothing happened.

Is anyone able to help me with a way around whatever is set up or what I should try? Im really struggling to figure out a way.

Comment: Try running wireshark during the nmap scan, the traces might shed some light.